# Bootstrap remove content: " "

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap, and in the `.row` class, they add

```
content: " ";
```

How can I remove it from my application? It is adding a line to the edge of the screen. I have tried this:

```
.main-content .row{
    content: "" !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I use chrome and inspect the element and uncheck the box it fixes the issue. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried this?

EDIT: To remove clearfix completely changed to `content: none;`

```
.main-content .row:before,
.main-content .row:after {
   content: none;
}
```

Comment: `content: ''` doesn't work but `content: none;` works.

Comment: I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `content: none`.